# Guest wifi network w/ different IP or range

Tags: network, wifi

How do you set up a wireless guest network with 2 routers with different ip ranges and still be able to see connected devices from internal router side. But not be able to see the internal router connections on the guest router. I want to have a guest network with a different range of IP address i.e. Internal 192.168.1.1 to 100 guest 192.168.1.101 to 200 or guest 192.168.2.1 to 100. I want to be able to identify guest connected devices solely by the IP address without having to set complete static IPs on all my devices or searching the MAC address to see which devices are on the internal network.

I forgot to add that I have seen this capability once on one router and that was an AirPort Extreme if anyone knows of one Router that can also do this without having to get two routers please let me know but I still would like to know how to configure it with 2 routers without causing Double NAT

Comment: you plug the WAN port of the guest router into a LAN port of the main router.

Comment: This is either a networking question or a product survey. Both of which are off-topic here (not really security questions).

Comment: I do apologize if I asked on the wrong forum but it is a security concern of mine since I'm having friends over and don't want them on my intranet. Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't tell you *all* the routers that have the capability to set up multiple networks on the LAN side.

Certainly the Ubiquity EdgeRouter's have that facility however at the physical layer.

You can also do it at a logical layer using VLAN's which most modern routers support. That isn't as secure but if real security is your aim, do not use consumer-grade routers.

One way to achieve what you want is to buy 2 Wi-Fi access points and connect them to your router. Set each on a different subnet. Say have the router on 192.168.1.*, one AP on 192.168.2.* and the 2nd AP on .3. Use the DHCP from each AP to deliver dynamic IP's. However, that on its own wouldn't be totally secure since a user could manually change their netmask to be able to access the other networks. To fix that, you need a router capable of firewalling between the networks. Ubiquity can do that for semi-pro/pro routers and CISCO too, doubtless one of the open source router OS's could also do it.

Ubuquiti EdgeRouter's are some of the best low-cost routers I've seen and have pro-level features at high-end consumer prices. They run a modified version of an open source router OS.

Comment: Thanks you for that information. That's what I been looking for. At least a baseline on higher end routers and what settings I should use on 2 access points. I'm a Networking major but never thought of using different subnets. I know it's not super secure but I just want the ability to identify users on my home network easily since my current cheapie router uses only the main intranet ip range without the ability to change subnets or ip ranges for the guest. I will look into that router and see about setting up an extra router I have laying around for my guest network for the time being.

Comment: Also look to see if your router does VLAN's. One thing you might be able to do is create two SSID's with different subnets on the single router. However, I would say that the more you configure on a consumer router, the more problems you will get. They just aren't powerful enough generally to do everything. If you can spring for a Ubiquity AP, that will also do everything you want I think and will offload a lot of processing from your router.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even with only one router depending of the capabilities of your router/AP. You can set up two different ESSIDs and use VLAN tagging for your purpose for example.

Your guest network can have its own ESSID, different auth method (WPA-PSK or whatever), can be separated with NAT and you can set up firewall in order to let them only internet access for example denying the access to the other network, it can be done easily. And in addition, you can set up to access to your guest network from the other ip range in order to control who is connecting.

Your question is too generic and only generic responses can be answered. :)

Comment: I already stated I knew of one router that had that capability. I asked what routers have that capability in one device. And how to set up 2 routers one for Intranet the other for Guest but not causing double NAT and still keeping them separate.